Arduino SPI Communication Delay Issue Between Two Pcap04 Readings
I’m using an Arduino to read data from a Pcap04 IC via SPI communication. The reading functionality works perfectly fine, but I noticed that there is a 10.31ms delay between each SPI data reading.
I’ve already checked my code, and there doesn’t seem to be any explicit delay that would cause this behavior.
However, after some testing, I found that if I add a 10ms delay after each SPI reading, the delay doesn’t actually show up in the logic analyzer. When I checked the SPI waveform with the logic analyzer, the delay between readings still remains at 10.31ms.
On the other hand, when I changed the delay to 20ms, the logic analyzer then shows a delay of 20.722ms between the readings.
This result indicates that setting a delay below 10.31ms doesn’t have any effect on the program, and it seems like there’s some factor causing an unpredictable delay between SPI readings.
Here is my code:


I’d like to ask anyone who has experience working with the Pcap04 IC: Have you encountered a similar issue? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

You didn't include any code. Please edit your code, copy and paste your code between the two "```".

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ah. it seems @hcheung commented based on that present in the original post, I rolled back my change.
